# How to return integers from a list recursively?

Tags: python

Created a function Integers in which a list Num containing integers,float and strings values.

Goal: function to return a list from Num that only displays the integers.

For example :

```
Num = ([10.4, 134, "134", "Stuff", 4, "5"])

[134, 4]
```

Condition : Using recursion only without any loops.

Comment: It would be better to post the code rather than explaining them in words with what error you are getting.

Comment: You are expected to first make an honest attempt at solving a homework task by yourselfPlease reconsider your question and take a look at [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Why do you need to do it recursively in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not really lend itself to recursion, but you can make it work:

```
def ints(lst, i=0):
    if i < len(lst):
        if isinstance(lst[i], int):
            yield lst[i]
        yield from ints(lst, i+1)

>>> list(ints([10.4, 134, "134", "Stuff", 4, "5"]))
[134, 4]
```

This uses a generator function to avoid passing lists around and running index to avoid the more expensive slicing.

For code readability, you could go with:

```
def ints(lst):
    if lst:
        head, *tail = ints
        if isinstance(head, int):
            yield head
        yield from ints(tail)
```

Comment: You should not reward people who ask homework questions without an honest attempt at solving the problem. It degrades the questions asked in the stackoverflow and degrades the quality of the website

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
 def only_ints(l, ret):
     if len(l) == 0:
         return ret
     x = l.pop()
     if type(x) is int:
        ret.append(x)
     return only_ints(l, ret)
```

To use it, run: `only_ints(Num, [])` (starting with an empty return list)

Input: `Num = [10.4, 134, "134", "s", 4]`

Output: `[4, 134]`